# htaccess block malicious post

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
12.126.10.1 - - [26/May/2017:10:54:38 +0800] "POST /core/cache/context_settings/zh/view.php HTTP/1.0" 200 1
```

I keep receive some malicious POST to my server, I wasn't able to clean/remove the cache folder.

how to create htaccess rules to block POST method to all file under /core/cache/

please help

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule to deny POST access to all files in /core/cache folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?core/cache/.+ - [R=403,L]
```